# Why isn't this Input Source usable in some apps?

Tags: keyboard, input-source

I created an  Input Source (Language Keyboard) with Ukelele. It worked fine on my BigSur. Now I moved the file to my new Macbook Pro Monterrey. The same thing happens whether it is on   `/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/HebrewYiddish.bundle` under root or Home.

When I am in Chrome, Atom, Terminal,  System Preferences search box, Pycharm, Zoom, Finder path-field, MacPass, LibreOffice Writer, or Firefox, I can easily switch.

When I am in Whatsapp, Pages, Safari, TextEdit, Reminders, Stickies, or Slack, I cannot. Selecting it in the taskbar just sends me back to another Input Source.  Likewise with the ⌃ -Space keyboard shortcut to switch Input Source (which of course pops up the new Monterrey keyboard-switching  overlay GUI). If I enable the Input Source in one app and switch to a problematic app, the Input Source changes away instantly when I open the app.

[image]

In Settings, it appears correctly regardless, and the keyboard image shows the keys correctly.

[image]

How can I keep the Input Source consistently available in all apps?

[image]

Comment: The Ukelele group can probably help too:  https://groups.google.com/g/ukelele-users?pli=1

Comment: @TomGewecke Indeed, I was using Ctl-Space on an external keyboard. But the same things happens when selecting with the mouse pointer in the GUI.

Comment: @TomGewecke I moved the bundle, then removed and added the Input source. I will report back on whether that works.

Comment: @TomGewecke Indeed, the problem occurs reproducible in Whatsapp, Pages, Safari, and Slack  and not in Terminal, Chrome, Atom, System Preferences search box, Pycharm ,  or Firefox! The difference in icon color in Sys Pref is a red herring, as it happens in either state. 
I edited the body to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was  to turn Karabiner Elements off; then on!

Then, both Ukelele and Karabiner work just fine.

This also solved a secondary problem with "ghost" Input Sources  reappearing repeatedly in the Input Sources list.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem without having Karabiner Elements ever on my computer.
I solved it by installing my Ukelele generated keyboard layout "for all users" instead for the "current user" using the ukelele organiser. This fix is the suggested in the google-group mentioned above.